# "ERROR: broken data stream when reading image file" (TrueType fonts libjpeg and PIL on OS X)

Tags: macos, wxpython, python-imaging-library, truetype, libjpeg

I'm running OS X 10.6.7, Python 2.6, and writing a small wxPython application that uses PIL to manipulate an image and add some text to it.

After quite a bit of configuration woes with attempting to get PIL running with libjpeg and PIL, I followed the instructions at [this site](http://pkarl.com/articles/freetype-jpeg-zlib-and-python-imaging-library-osx-/).

Upon running `python setup.py build_ext -i` (from inside the Imaging-1.1.7 folder) I get:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version       1.1.7
platform      darwin 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49)
          [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- TKINTER support available
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
--- FREETYPE2 support available
--- LITTLECMS support available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Additionally, running `python selftest.py` in the Imaging-1.1.7 install folder, I get:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 TEST SUMMARY 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Python modules loaded from ./PIL
Binary modules loaded from ./PIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- PIL CORE support ok
--- TKINTER support ok
--- JPEG support ok
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support ok
--- FREETYPE2 support ok
--- LITTLECMS support ok
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Running selftest:
--- 57 tests passed.
```

However, when rendering my first PIL image in my own code, I still get:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1290, in resize self.load()
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 215, in load raise_ioerror(e)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 52, in raise_ioerror
raise IOError(message + " when reading image file")
IOError: broken data stream when reading image file
```

I'm kind of at a loss as to what to try next. Any ideas? The code that is causing this crash seems to be:

```
try:
    self.img = self.img.resize((self.screenwidth, self.screenheight), 
            Image.ANTIALIAS)
    except IOError, e:
        print "Error resizing: " + str(e)
        self.img = self.img.resize((self.screenwidth, self.screenheight))
        raise
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I no longer have access to this environment and cannot check. My solution was to switch the base environment to Linux..

Comment: Hi tom10, yes import _imaging is working properly. I can open, resize, crop, create thumbnails with images using python command but it's not working in app :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider uninstalling PIL and following the instructions on this website -
http://jetfar.com/libjpeg-and-python-imaging-pil-on-snow-leopard/

In particular, it appears that you want to make sure that libjpeg is at version **6b**, not **8c** (see below)

---

I am able to reproduce this with Mac OS X 10.5 using macports

This is related to a another question:
[How to solve IOError:broken data stream when reading image file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652249/how-to-solve-ioerrorbroken-data-stream-when-reading-image-file)

The answer there indicates that the bug might have something to do with libjpeg

As far as I can tell, the error appears to be caused by a forward incompatibility with libjpeg v8c.

I cannot determine what is causing this exactly; all I can say is that on a variety of other systems I use that aren't exhibiting this behavior error (OS X 10.5 with fink, Redhat 5.2, Ubuntu 11.10 and 10.10), they all use libjpeg 6b.  Only macports uses 8c, and macports is the only system where I am getting this error.

Comment: I will check this once more on Tuesday, no I can't do this :( Thanks for advice!

Comment: Yep... the libjpeg8c was the issue. I've uninstalled it and installed 6b again. Reinstalled PIL and it's working. I read somewhere that this might be the issue but somehow ignored it. Thank you very much. The bounty is yours :D

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use PIL with the [homebrew package manager](https://brew.sh/).

Comment: Thanks for info, but I wasn't working with Mac. I only had similar issue like in this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar error when reading .jpg file with an up-to-date Python environment and Sierra Mac OS. I've found a quick workaround which consists to convert all the .jpg files to .png files Hoping that can help someone else.