# error in caffe.io.load_image(), it cannot load image

Tags: python, caffe, pycaffe

when I run the command in python:

```
import caffe
img = caffe.io.load_image('bird.jpg')
```

it raised an error:

> ValueError: Could not load "bird.jpg"
>   Please see documentation at: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#external-libraries

I find some solutions at [caffe users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/ltdeqU4hiaw) and [Delbert's Blog](http://delbert.me/archives/753.html), but they don't work, How can I fix it?

Comment: shouldn't is be [`caffe.io.load_image`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/io.py#L278)? can you open `'bird.jpg'` in any external tool? is it possible the image file is corrupt?

Comment: Sorry about that, I got a mistake, it is **caffe.io.load_image**

Comment: how about the other questions I asked? is it possible that the image is corrupted?

Comment: can you load other images?

Comment: I can not load any images, I found solutions at webpages above, it mentioned, there is something wrong with Pillow, but I still can not solver this problem according to their solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem, here is the details below:

First, I recheck this error imformation:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scikit_image-0.11.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/skimage/io/_plugins/pil_plugin.py", line 52, in imread
>   raise ValueError('Could not load "%s"\nPlease see documentation at: %s' % (fname, site))
>   ValueError: Could not load "bird.jpg"
>   Please see documentation at: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#external-libraries

it is a error with **imread**, I checked the file **pil_plugin.py**, I found it got thiss error when it came to

```
im = Image.open(fname)
try:
    # this will raise an IOError if the file is not readable
    im.getdata()[0]
except IOError:
    site = "http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#external-libraries"
    raise ValueError('Could not load "%s"\nPlease see documentation at: %s' % (fname, site))
else:
    return pil_to_ndarray(im, dtype=dtype, img_num=img_num)
```

so it is most probably wrong with **im.getdata()**, then I run it and it raise an error:

> im.getdata() IOError: broken data stream when reading image file.

then I followed [Matt W-D's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245619/error-broken-data-stream-when-reading-image-file-truetype-fonts-libjpeg-and) to reinstall jpeg6,  delete the **PIL** package installed by Pillow, and reinstall PIL by downloading file from http://effbot.org/downloads#pil.

At last, I linked the libjpeg

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib
sudo ldconfigthe
```

The error disappeared